# file_get_contents Not allowed in Themes?

Tags: theme-development, themes

I'm using `file_get_contents` in a theme development (in a widget of the theme). However the theme check plugin gives me following warning:

```
WARNING: file_get_contents was found in the file file.php possible file operations.

Line 49: $data = file_get_contents ( 'http://example.com');
Line 62: $count= file_get_contents ( $cfile );
```

My question is that if it is not allowed in the themes, is there any alternative for this function which can be used?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `Line 49: $data = file_get_contents ( 'http://example.com');`

Don't use `file_get_contents` to download web page. WordPress has HTTP API for such needs. In your case, I would suggest you to use `wp_remote_get( 'http://example.com' );` function instead of `file_get_contents`.

Further reading:

1. [WordPress HTTP API](http://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API)
2. [`wp_remote_get`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_API/wp_remote_get) function.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have any issue with PHP. I'm just checking my theme with the theme checker plugin, and that gives me this warning, which means WP does not recommend using this function in the theme development. But I'll check wp_remote_get as you suggested.

Comment: @eugene What if I want to read a file that is being uploaded, wp_remote_get need a valid url, I only want to check the uploaded file, but using file_get_contents won't pass the theme check

Comment: @nackle read about Filesystem API http://codex.wordpress.org/Filesystem_API